# CSS is not applying on creating pdf from ABC pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, abcpdf

**Problem:**

I am passing HTML and creating pdf through ABC pdf.

But the CSS are not applied on the content and pdf created is not as expected.

Here is my code can u please suggest what is the problem or how we can apply CSS...

```
    public static String CreateHtmlFile(String strHtmlCode)
    {
        String Modifiedhtml = @"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"" ""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd""><html class="" _Telerik_IE9"" xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"">" + strHtmlCode;
        Modifiedhtml = Modifiedhtml.Remove(Modifiedhtml.IndexOf(@"//<![CDATA["), (Modifiedhtml.IndexOf("//]]>") - Modifiedhtml.IndexOf(@"//<![CDATA[")));
        string[] stringSeparators = new string[] { "PdfCreator" };
        var baseUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).First();
        Modifiedhtml = Modifiedhtml.Replace(@"href=""../", (@"href=""" + baseUrl));
        Modifiedhtml = Modifiedhtml.Replace(@"href=""/", (@"href=""" + baseUrl));
        Doc theDoc = new Doc();
        theDoc.HtmlOptions.UseScript = false;
        //theDoc.Width = 1125;
        String s = string.Empty;
        //s = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\test.html");
        theDoc.Page = theDoc.AddPage();
        int theID;
        theID = theDoc.AddHtml(strHtmlCode);
        //theID = theDoc.AddHtml(s);
        while (true)
        {
            theDoc.FrameRect(); // add a black border
            if (!theDoc.Chainable(theID))
                break;
            theDoc.Page = theDoc.AddPage();
            theID = theDoc.AddImageToChain(theID);
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= theDoc.PageCount; i++)
        {
            theDoc.PageNumber = i;
            theDoc.Flatten();
        }
        theDoc.Save(@"D:\two\pagedhtml4.pdf");
        theDoc.Clear();
        return String.Empty;
    }
```

strHtmlCode is the HTML of the page which we have to convert in PDF.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Might not be useful in this context, but I recommend looking into phantomJS as a way to create pdfs. It's essentially a headless browser that renders the page with the option of creating a pdf

Comment: I may be wrong, but doesn't ABC pdf require that the relevant CSS be embedded in the HTML you are transforming?  In other words, I'm not sure it actually follows URL references.

Comment: ABC pdf is commercial and they provide tech support also so you should go there first.

Comment: Can u provide me some supporting links where i can learn how to create pdf from phantom js

Answer (score 5):

From the [WebSupergoo doc page](http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/source/5-abcpdf/doc/1-methods/addhtml.htm) on the `AddHtml` Function:

> Adds a block of HTML styled text to the current page.

HTML styled text does **not** support CSS. For full featured, standard CSS, you want `AddImageHtml`.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `strHtmlCode` into the `AddHtml` function. It looks like you really want to pass in `Modifiedhtml` instead.